# is there any ways to modify a process's exit code before its parent process finishes waiting?

Tags: python, process, operating-system

we fork a new python sub-process, then we wait until it's over and get the exit code.if the code is 0, we regard it as succ, otherwise fail.
however,sometimes, the process finished the bussiness operation correctly,but return non-zero code due to the system or the interpreter itself, the code may be 1,or -1112334 etc. from the business view, it should be regarded as succ, but fail from the exit code. so we need to set a flag to ensure the exit code be 0 if the code finished business need.

for example,

```
def main():
    print("succ!!")
main()
## here we call some functions to force the exit code to be zero,even code below will fail.
print(1/0) # this must result in the process to fail.
```

we tried atexit package:

```
def main():
    print("succ!!")
main()
import atexit,sys
def hock():
    sys.exit(0)
atexit.register(hock)
print(1/0)
```

but no effect, atexit only helps to execute some clean work, but no effect on the exit code, even though the atexit functions may fail, no effect on the process exit code.

so anyone can help me?

code is above, i have no idea.

Comment: Why specifically is the subprocess returning with non-zero status? For an example, is an exception being raised?

Comment: If an exception from `print(1/0)` terminates the process, I don't think anything else will run afterwards. from the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) docs: "*Functions thus registered are automatically executed upon ***normal*** interpreter termination.*"

Comment: It's an XY problem. Why not fix the bug which causes a nonzero exit code? Anyway, why not provide the information on completing the workload to the parent process by other mechanisms, such as a file, pipe, etc.?

Comment: because the parent process not know what script to run in child process, it only cares the exit code of the child, and juede succ or fail according the code; but sometimes, the child finish major work, and fail to do some clean job, leading to none-zero code.
for example, the child sends a file to others,and succfully, but fail to  close connection in a destructor, leading to a none-0 code.however, the script should be regarded as cuss.
our case like above.we have other means to resolve the problem, such make a new flag. but we not want to change the logic code.